# JS AJAX - как узнать, в чем моя ошибка? Возвращает SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, ajax

Вот код
https://jsfiddle.net/f9e0khoo/
Здесь только JS, потому что все равно без БД работать не будет. 
Вот, что возвращает:

```
{readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
jquery-3.2.1.js:9566 XHR finished loading: POST "http://sportpit/alotoadmin/item/createcolor".
send @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9566
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.js:9173
createColor @ edit?id=25:572
onclick @ VM3882 edit?id=25:1
edit?id=25:584 parsererror
edit?id=25:585 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery-3.2.1.js:8754)
    at done (jquery-3.2.1.js:9222)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.js:9514)
```

Как узнать, в чем ошибка то?

Comment: Очень похоже на ответ не в `json` формате либо в невалидном `json` формате

Answer (score 0):

Выполните этот запрос в браузере, получите на руки ответ - json-документ, используйте [jsonlint](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/jsonlint.1.html). Если документ небольшой, то ошибку вы найдете глазами - считайте парность кавычек, фигурных и квадратных скобок.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я поменял запрос с POST на GET, взял ссылку из вкладки Network в браузере, поменял обратно на POST, ввел в адресную строку ссылку и получил следующее:
"{"status":false,"message":"Invalid request"}"
То же самое, если не менять обратно (оставить GET).
Понятнее не стало. В чем же моя ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте : `curl -Xpost "http://sportpit/alotoadmin/item/createcolor" -d "color_id=color_id" -d "id=123"`